# Setting android:debuggable="true" causes Titanium App to crash

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to debug my app using DDMS but when I set android:debuggable="true" in my tiapp.xml the app crashes every time I start it. I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S6.

Comment: Sdk version, Logs? I'm test it on 5.2.2 and works

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up the project and uninstalling/reinstalling the app?